# Reading from XML file into a DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, dataset

I try to fill a `DataSet` with values from a XML file like this so I can then fill a `DataGridView` with the values:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\aaa.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataSource = "Products";
```

But I don't get anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where  is datagridview1.databind()

Comment: My application is a WinFor application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your data loaded will be called `Products` in your data set??

Try to verify by inspecting the tables in the dataset after you've loaded the data:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds. ReadXml(@"C:\aaa.xml");

foreach(DataTable t in ds.Tables)
{
   string tableName = t.TableName;   // put a breakpoint here - inspect the table names
}
```

If you want to use simply show the first table loaded, try this snippet:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds. ReadXml(@"C:\aaa.xml");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
```

Comment: The DataTable example is easier but I can not get it working.

Comment: @Lars: the `DataTable` appears to be not working indeed - I fixed my post back to using the `DataSet` and automatically picking the first table in that dataset for binding to the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\aaa.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.Datamember= "Products";
```

Comment: he wrote both as datasource check once

Comment: True - a brief **explanation** might be helpful, too - not just lines of code....

Comment: yes my problem was that I wrote datasource instead of datamember :S

Comment: What if you dont know the Datamember? how do you read that without reading the xml file?